# Get pixels to the left of an element Javascript only seems to work when window is slightly resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have now updated the question. I have figured out most of the problem mentioned earlier before this edit.
Here are some screen shots:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7zakvgi1emyzxk/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-14%20at%208.05.22%20PM.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9a4wg8mwx7nj6p8/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-14%20at%208.05.30%20PM.png?dl=0

The first link shows what the page looks like onload before you ever resize the window (look at the white popup).

The second screen shot shows what the page looks like after the page has loaded and you resize the window (look at the white popup).

I am trying to achieve what is in the second screen shot, but without having to resize the window to get it like that (look at the white popup).

Here is my current code:

***CSS***

For all the buttons inside the white popup.

```
#optionsContainer * {
  font-size:.8em;
  background-color:#fff !important;
  border-radius:0px;
  -webkit-transition-property: none;
  -moz-transition-property: none;
  -o-transition-property: none;
  transition-property: none;
  color:#000 !important;
  border-top:2px solid #CBCBCB;
  width:200px;
  padding:8px;
  margin:0;
}
```

For the white popup:

```
#optionsContainer
{
display:none;
background-color:#fff;
width:200px;
margin:0;
z-index:20;
position:absolute;
box-shadow:10px 10px 199px #000;
padding:0;
}
```

For the button right above the white popup (this button opens the white popup):

```
#options
{
background-image:url("icons/options.png");
width:32px !important;
height:32px !important;
vertical-align:-12px;
}
```

***HTML:***
optionsContainer (the white popup):

```
<div id="optionsContainer" class="optionsContainer">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="peopleButtonTrigger" onclick="alert('test');" value="Messages From These People">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="settings" onclick="settings();" value="Settings">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="logout" onclick="location='logout.html';" value="Logout">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="slideShow" paused='true' onclick="setSlideShow();" value="Slide Show">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="viewIntroductionSlideAgain" onclick="resetIntroductionSlider();" value="View Introduction">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="deleteAccount" onclick="location='deleteAccount.html';" value="Delete Account">
            <input type="button" class="optionsContainer" id="aboutButton" onclick="showAbout();" value="About">
</div>
```

Options button (opens the white popup list):

```
        <input type="image" src="icons/options.png" alt="options" id="options" onclick="document.getElementById('optionsContainer').style.display = 'block';">
```

Body tag:

```
<body id="body" onload="setOptionsListPosition();" onresize="setOptionsListPosition();">
```

***Javascript (the setOptionsListPosition(); function):***

```
function setOptionsListPosition()
    {
         var options = document.getElementById('options');
         var rect = options.getBoundingClientRect();
         document.getElementById('optionsContainer').style.left = Math.floor(rect.left)-200+32+'px';
         document.getElementById('optionsContainer').style.top = Math.floor(rect.top)+32+'px';
    }
```

Please ask any questions if you don't understand. Also there is a div which the options button is enclosed inside of and it has a 2% padding, but I don't see how that could make it behave that way. Could you also explain why it might do that? Thank you!

Comment: `$('#options')` and than only one line after you use `document.getElementById` any reason for that?

Comment: no. I generally try to use javascript, but if I have to I use jquery. I couldn't find a javascript function that did the same thing for `$('#options').position(); `

Comment: than look at `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` Method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The cause of the issue was that the javascript function was being called twice at the same time, which caused the browser to get mixed up. To fix the problem I made these changes to the `body` tag:

***OLD:***

```
<body id="body" onload="setOptionsListPosition();" onresize="setOptionsListPosition();">
```

***NEW:***

```
<body id="body" onload="setOptionsListPosition();" onresize="window.setTimeout(function(){setOptionsListPosition();}, 30);">
```

The new version waits 30/1000 of a second and then executes the function. It is very strange, it seems as though when the page loads it would fire the `onload` event AND the `resize` event even though the resize never occurred. If someone could explain why that happened I would like that. Thank you!